# Is there a good alternative to "Test & Feedback" browser extension for manual test execution of Azure DevOps Test Plan module Test Cases

Tags: testing, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We are using Azure DevOps for development and Test Management. "Test & Feedback" is the only extension for manual tests execution I'm aware of that can be used with DevOps and has many flaws. Can someone recommend any other test execution plugins or software with works with DevOps Test Plan module?
Also, does anyone know how to bypass some of the "Test & Feedback" flaws? like one the annoying once below:

- Inability to view an image attached to a test case in full size. Only can use magnifying option of the plugin which is very awkward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a good alternative to “Test & Feedback” browser extension for manual test execution of Azure DevOps Test Plan module Test Cases

AFAIK, there is no such good alternative to “Test & Feedback” browser extension for manual test execution of Azure DevOps Test Plan module Test Cases.

Test & Feedback extension helps teams perform exploratory testing and provide feedback. Everyone in the team, such as developers, product owners, managers, UX or UI engineers, marketing teams, early adopters, and other stakeholders can use the extension to submit bugs or provide feedback and contribute to the quality of your product. Just as you know, Test & Feedback only extension for manual tests execution, there is no better and comprehensive expansion that can completely replace it at this moment.

Certainly, there are still many areas for improvement in the extension test and feedback. We can feed our suggestions back to the extension author to help build a better extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-exploratorytesting-web&ssr=false#qna

Note: Someone has already made the same request, you can also submit your request there, if the same request is requested by multiple people, MS may give priority to it

Comment: Thanks Leo, it does help.